# Hidden Dependencies With Mixed Quantifiers

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I just read about hidden dependencies in Barwise's LPL book, and have a questions about certain proofs.

I understand the idea that using existential instantiation in a predicate that has an arbitrary constant depends on that constant, and so you can't use universal generalization on that predicate. But what about statements that are obviously true like $$\exists y\in \mathbb{R} \,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}(x+y=x)$$

Would the proof for this statement violate the hidden dependency rules that say universal generalization after an existential instantiation that depends on the constant to be generalized is not allowed?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to speculate whether a proof of some statement must violate some rule. There are an infinite number of incorrect proofs of any statement. You need to propose a proof of the statement in question: e.g., in your example the one that offers $0$ as the witness for $y$, and then ask whether the proposed proof is correct.

Comment: @Rob Arthan Let $y=0$. Take some arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $x+y=x+0=x$. Since $x$ was arbitrary we have $\forall x (x+y=x)$, and therefore $\exists y\forall x (x+y=x)$. Would something like this work?

Comment: Yes, but you need to turn it into a proof in the formalism of LPL and then ask whether your transcription into LPL was correct.

Comment: Right, I was just concerned about the existential instantiation that follows the universal generalization. But seeing that y does not depend on x clears up the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Why do such dependencies never seem to come up in mathematical proofs in say algebra or analysis? I haven't come across one anyway.

Comment: In algebra or analysis, apart from any free variables introduced in a premise or  in any active statement prior to it, no other free variables can appear in the statement resulting from that premise being discharged. Might this have something to do with it?

Comment: @DanChristensen The standard example illustrating these "hidden" dependencies is the difference between pointwise and uniform continuity. The reason a proof of pointwise continuity doesn't in general work for uniform continuity is exactly these "hidden" dependencies. I'm having a hard time understanding what you're saying in your second comment.

Comment: @DerekElkins I think that's a different kind of dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof for this statement is simply about showing the existence of such a $y$ for which the statement that $\exists y \forall x (x+y = y)$.

In other words, is asking if there exists an additive identity $y\in \mathbb R$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb R(x+y=x).$

Well, we do know that $$\forall x \in \mathbb R\,(x+ 0 = x).$$

So there does in fact exist a $y \in \mathbb R$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb R$, it is true that $x+y=x$, because we can use $0$ as a witness for $y\in \mathbb R$.

That leaves us with only $$\forall x \in \mathbb R( x+0 = x)$$

Comment: It wouldn't be an issue to use universal generalization here then?

Comment: Not at all, Simplicio.

Comment: @Simplicio:see my comment on the question. You need to turn amWhy's proposed proof into a proof in the system of LPL and see whether your transcription correct. If you get it right, you'll find that because the witness $0$ does not depend on $x$, the proof won't violate the rule on universal generalisation.

Comment: So the "hidden dependencies" consideration only matters if we use existential instantiation in a way that depends on the arbitrary constant, and THEN try to use universal generalization?

Comment: Indeed, @Simplicio

Comment: Uh, universal generalization would be $\forall x ~ x + 0 = x \vdash \forall y ~ \forall x ~ x + y = x$, which would be wrong.  That is because $0$ exists in outstanding assumptions (such as $\forall x~ Sx \ne 0$).

Answer (score 1):

[Aside: I'm increasing becoming of the opinion that "illustrating" logic with natural language sentences, especially "every day" sentences, is harmful. The connections between natural language and logic are quite complex, and one should know logic *before* trying to do this, and of course it's completely unnecessary if you're not interested in linguistics. I don't have a problem with reading formal expressions into natural language, but the image of that is a highly stylized subset of natural language.]

I strongly prefer a sequent-style presentation of logic rules/proofs (with proof objects but I won't go that far here) as opposed to the vertical nested lists of Fitch style.  This is mostly a superficial distinction, but I find it makes it easier to discuss the rules of logic. Basically, you write out the lists horizontally instead of vertically, e.g.
$$\begin{align}
& |\ 1.\ P & & \\
& \underline{|\ 2.\ Q} &\text{ becomes } &\quad P, Q \vdash R\\
& |\ 3.\ R & & 
\end{align}$$
Usually, the list of premises "$P, Q$" is called $\Gamma$ leading to $\Gamma \vdash R$. Then $\Gamma, S \vdash R$ would mean $P,Q,S \vdash R$. Rules are then presented vertically, e.g. conjunction introduction:
$$\frac{\Gamma\vdash P \qquad \Gamma\vdash Q}{\Gamma\vdash P\land Q}$$
This reads as "if $\Gamma \vdash P$ and $\Gamma \vdash Q$ then $\Gamma \vdash P\land Q$". This corresponds to the nested lists in Fitch-style. The benefit of Fitch-style is that we don't have to keep copying the premises (i.e. $\Gamma$) which is good for actually doing proofs. The downside in that it is awkward to refer to the whole collection of premises (the context, i.e. $\Gamma$) which is bad for explaining some proof rules. Here is the rule for universal generalization in sequent-style: $$\frac{\Gamma \vdash P \qquad x \notin \text{FV}(\Gamma)}{\Gamma\vdash\forall x.P}$$ where $\text{FV}(\Gamma)$ means the set of free variables of $\Gamma$ which is just the union of the set of free variables of each predicate in $\Gamma$. With this, it's very easy to see what goes wrong with a proof of say $\exists y.\forall x.x+y=0$ that doesn't go wrong with $\forall x.\exists y.x+y=0$ or with $\exists y.\forall x.x + y = x$.

Let's start with the true statement $\forall x.\exists y.x+y = 0$. Writing $\cdot$ for the context with no premises, we get the proof:
$$\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{}{\cdot\vdash 0=0}}{\cdot\vdash x+(-x)=0}}{\cdot\vdash\exists y.x+y=0}\qquad \cfrac{}{x\notin\text{FV}(\cdot)}}{\cdot\vdash\forall x.\exists y.x+y=0}$$

Next consider the following proof of $\exists y.\forall x.x+y=x$:
$$\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{}{\cdot\vdash x=x}}{\cdot\vdash x+0=x}\qquad \cfrac{}{x\notin\text{FV}(\cdot)}}{\cdot\vdash\forall x.x+0=x}}{\cdot\vdash \exists y.\forall x.x+y=x}$$

Now see what happens when we try to do something along the lines of the first proof for $\exists y.\forall x.x+y=0$:
$$\cfrac{???}{\cdot\vdash\exists y.\forall x.x+y=0}$$
Immediately, we seem to be stuck. We'd like to substitute $(-x)$ for $y$, but $x$ isn't in scope and attempting to do such a substitution anyway would lead to something like $\forall z.z+(-x) = 0$ because capture-avoiding substitution would require us to rename the variable bound by $\forall$. But we're clever, we continue as follows:
$$\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{}{z = -x\vdash 0 = 0}}{z = -x\vdash x + (-x) =0}}{z = -x\vdash x + z = 0}\qquad x\notin\text{FV}(z = -x)}{z = -x\vdash \forall x.x+z = 0}}{z = -x\vdash\exists y.\forall x.x+y=0}}{\cdot\vdash\exists y.\forall x.x+y=0}$$
This proof almost succeeds, but it fails the side-condition on universal generalization that $x\notin\text{FV}(z = -x)$. That is, $z$ has a (now not so) "hidden" dependency on $x$. This makes complete sense. If we have a premise involving $x$, here $z = -x$, then $x$ isn't completely unconstrained. If we rewrite the second proof to be more like this failed proof, we see the difference:
$$\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{}{z=0\vdash x=x}}{z=0\vdash x+0=x}}{z=0\vdash x+z=x}\qquad \cfrac{}{x\notin\text{FV}(z=0)}}{z=0\vdash\forall x.x+z=x}}{\cfrac{z=0\vdash\exists y.\forall x.x+y=x}{\cdot\vdash \exists y.\forall x.x+y=x}}$$